# Wordpress - Adding pages to a menu - keeping their hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, navigation, nav

hoping someone can help...

I've never had this issue before but I'm currently working on a website with lots and lots of pages.

I have created all of the pages, specifying all child and grandchild pages, but then I tick them all and add them to a menu (Appearance - Menus), they lose their hierarchy.

Normally this isn't an issue because for smaller sites I can just drag them to the correct position, but for this site and future sites with lots of pages, this would take a long time.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to add all pages to a menu and keep the hierarchy.

Or is there a fundamental reason why this isn't a feature - are page hierarchies and menu hierarchies different things perhaps?

Any help anyone could I've would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this plugin a try: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-menu-from-pages/

It somewhat mimics the WordPress menu functionality prior to these days of having Appearance > Menus available.

Comment: Looks Perfect! I'll give this a shot - Not sure why they don't build this functionality into core. I guess there must be a reason.

Thanks a bunch Dave :)